# Using loops to fill the sqlite database of coredata

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using coredata relationships first time.I have two entities School and Book those attributes have following attributes.
School:id,userid,permission
Book:id,name,description,duration,hour.
There is one to many relationship between School and Book.My target is to get data using relationship from Book based School.userid and I am able to achieve it so far.Following is the code that I am using to save and fetch.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *School = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"School" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [School setValue:self.idTextField.text forKey:@"id"];
    [School setValue:self.userIdTextField.text forKey:@"userid"];
    [School setValue:self.permissionTextField.text forKey:@"permission"];

    NSManagedObject *Book = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [Book setValue:self.Id.text forKey:@"id"];
    [Book setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [Book setValue:self.descriptionTextField.text forKey:@"discription"];
    [Book setValue:self.hoursTextField.text forKey:@"hours"];
    [Book setValue:self.durationTextField.text forKey:@"duration"];
    [Book setValue:School forKey:@"School"];



    [School mutableSetValueForKey:@"Book"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now,I want to populate coredata automatically without going through the interface for save using loops.I am able to work on loops till filling School. But,I am not able to fill Book table using loop corrosponding to particular user id.Please guide how this can be achieved.Any help and suggestion would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code for loop that you are using to populate IDUSUNP

Comment: @user1000 ,added..kindly check and help.

Comment: Please check the answer, if you face problem ask in comments

Comment: Please give the feedback, if the answer solves your problem or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add the for loop in each if statement and set the values of your choice

```
    if(i>0 &&i<=100)
            {
                [School setValue:@"Apple" forKey:@"userid"];

                for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    NSManagedObject *Book= [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    [Book setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j + 10] forKey:@"id"];
                    [Book setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %i", j] forKey:@"name"];
                    [Book setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] forKey:@"hours"];

                   [Book setValue:School forKey:@"School"];

                }



            }
 else if(i>100 && i<=200){
            [School setValue:@"iPhone" forKey:@"userid"];
             for(int j = 10; j < 20; j++) {
                    NSManagedObject *wouni = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    [Book setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j + 10] forKey:@"id"];
                    [Book setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %i", j] forKey:@"name"];
                    [Book setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] forKey:@"hours"];


                   [Book setValue:School forKey:@"School"];

                }




        }
```

**Note:** If this is an inverse one to many relationship from School to wouni (one object of School is associated with many objects of wounis)
then you dont need to add wounis back to School, because CoreData will take care of the inverse relation

Lastly, I think you dont need the following statement in every if condition,

```
if (![context save:&error]) {
          NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

    }
```

just write it once at the end of the function

For predicate part, I think you should add predicate like this:

```
[r setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.userid = %@",userid]];
```

Comment: @Prez please check the updated answer, I have added the predicate part, does this solve your problem?

Comment: Ok,m trying will let you know the results .

Comment: @Prez ok good, if you face problem, please ask further questions

Comment: I have done the changes according to your instructions and updated here in question also but it brings me result for userid "Apple" only but for iphone it shows data count and data as 0.

Comment: @Prez Please change this condition else if(i>10 && i<=20) to else if(i>100 && i<=200) and then try again

Comment: I have checked upto 500 records and it works,please explain how does the j loop works here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151636/discussion-between-user1000-and-prez).